# Add function keys to keybind

Tags: python, keypress, midi

I am trying to change the keybind for a online virtual piano like this
`self.virtualPianoScale = list("1!2@34$5%6^78*9(0qQwWeErtTyYuiIoOpPasSdDfgGhHjJklLzZxcCvVbBnm")`

but I would like to change it to q1w2er3t4y5ui6o7p[8]9\0-= and there are 3 notes here.

for low note must press F1 for keybind q1w2er3t4y5ui6o7p[8]9\0-=

for middle note F2 q1w2er3t4y5ui6o7p[8]9\0-=

and high note F3 keybind same q1w2er3t4y5ui6o7p[8]9\0-=

how i change like this?

reference ([virtual piano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjkM-V-OUlM&t=186s) & [undawn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNuFwFADylw))

here is the full code:

```
import os


class MidiFile:
    startSequence = [   [0x4D,0x54,0x68,0x64], #MThd
                        [0x4D,0x54,0x72,0x6B], #MTrk
                        [0xFF] #FF
                    ]
    
    typeDict = {0x00 : "Sequence Number",
                0x01 : "Text Event",
                0x02 : "Copyright Notice",
                0x03 : "Sequence/Track Name",
                0x04 : "Instrument Name",
                0x05 : "Lyric",
                0x06 : "Marker",
                0x07 : "Cue Point",
                0x20 : "MIDI Channel Prefix",
                0x2F : "End of Track",
                0x51 : "Set Tempo",
                0x54 : "SMTPE Offset",
                0x58 : "Time Signature",
                0x59 : "Key Signature",
                0x7F : "Sequencer-Specific Meta-event",
                0x21 : "Prefix Port",
                0x20 : "Prefix Channel",
                0x09 : "Other text format [0x09]",
                0x08 : "Other text format [0x08]",
                0x0A : "Other text format [0x0A]",
                0x0C : "Other text format [0x0C]"
                }

    
    def __init__(self,midi_file,verbose=False,debug=False):
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.debug = debug
        
        self.bytes = -1
        self.headerLength = -1
        self.headerOffset = 23
        self.format = -1
        self.tracks = -1
        self.division = -1
        self.divisionType = -1
        self.itr = 0
        self.runningStatus = -1
        self.tempo = 0
        
        self.midiRecord_list = []
        self.record_file = "midiRecord.txt"
        self.midi_file = midi_file
        
        self.deltaTimeStarted = False
        self.deltaTime = 0
        
        self.key_press_count = 0
        
        self.virtualPianoScale = list("1!2@34$5%6^78*9(0qQwWeErtTyYuiIoOpPasSdDfgGhHjJklLzZxcCvVbBnm")
        
        self.startCounter = [0] * len(MidiFile.startSequence)
        
        self.runningStatusSet = False
        
        self.events = []
        self.notes = []
        self.success = False
        
        print("Processing",midi_file)
        try:
            with open(self.midi_file,"rb") as f:
                self.bytes = bytearray(f.read())
            self.readEvents()
            print(self.key_press_count,"notes processed")
            self.clean_notes()
            self.success = True
        finally:
            self.save_record(self.record_file)
    
    def checkStartSequence(self):
        for i in range(len(self.startSequence)):
            if(len(self.startSequence[i]) == self.startCounter[i]):
                return True
        return False
    
    def skip(self,i):
        self.itr += i
    
    def readLength(self):
        contFlag = True
        length = 0
        while(contFlag):
            if((self.bytes[self.itr] & 0x80) >> 7 == 0x1):
                length = (length << 7) + (self.bytes[self.itr] & 0x7F)
            else:
                contFlag = False
                length = (length << 7) + (self.bytes[self.itr] & 0x7F)
            self.itr += 1
        return length
    
    def readMTrk(self):
        length = self.getInt(4)
        self.log("MTrk len",length)
        self.readMidiTrackEvent(length)
    
    def readMThd(self):
        self.headerLength = self.getInt(4)
        self.log("HeaderLength",self.headerLength)
        self.format = self.getInt(2)
        self.tracks = self.getInt(2)
        div = self.getInt(2)
        self.divisionType = (div & 0x8000) >> 16
        self.division = div & 0x7FFF
        self.log("Format %d\nTracks %d\nDivisionType %d\nDivision %d" % (self.format,self.tracks,self.divisionType,self.division))
    
    def readText(self,length):
        s = ""
        start = self.itr
        while(self.itr < length+start):
            s += chr(self.bytes[self.itr])
            self.itr+=1
        return s
    
    def readMidiMetaEvent(self,deltaT):
        type = self.bytes[self.itr]
        self.itr+=1
        length = self.readLength()
        
        try:
            eventName = self.typeDict[type]
        except:
            eventName = "Unknown Event " + str(type)
            
        self.log("MIDIMETAEVENT",eventName,"LENGTH",length,"DT",deltaT)
        if(type == 0x2F):
            self.log("END TRACK")
            self.itr += 2
            return False
        elif(type in [0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0A,0x0C]):
            self.log("\t",self.readText(length))
        elif(type == 0x51):
            tempo = round(60000000/self.getInt(3))
            self.tempo = tempo
            
            self.notes.append([(self.deltaTime/self.division),"tempo=" + str(tempo)])
            self.log("\tNew tempo is", str(tempo))
        else:
            self.itr+= length
        return True
        
    def readMidiTrackEvent(self,length):
        self.log("TRACKEVENT")
        self.deltaTime = 0
        start = self.itr
        continueFlag = True
        while(length > self.itr - start and continueFlag):
            deltaT= self.readLength()
            self.deltaTime += deltaT
            
            if(self.bytes[self.itr] == 0xFF):
                self.itr+= 1
                continueFlag = self.readMidiMetaEvent(deltaT)
            elif(self.bytes[self.itr] >= 0xF0 and self.bytes[self.itr] <= 0xF7):
                self.runningStatusSet = False
                self.runningStatus = -1
                self.log("RUNNING STATUS SET:","CLEARED")
            else:
                self.readVoiceEvent(deltaT)
        self.log("End of MTrk event, jumping from",self.itr,"to",start+length)
        self.itr = start+length
                
    def readVoiceEvent(self,deltaT):
        if(self.bytes[self.itr] < 0x80 and self.runningStatusSet):
            type = self.runningStatus
            channel = type & 0x0F
        else:
            type = self.bytes[self.itr]
            channel = self.bytes[self.itr] & 0x0F
            if(type >= 0x80 and type <= 0xF7):
                self.log("RUNNING STATUS SET:",hex(type))
                self.runningStatus = type
                self.runningStatusSet = True
            self.itr += 1
        
        if(type >> 4 == 0x9):
            #Key press
            key = self.bytes[self.itr]
            self.itr += 1
            velocity = self.bytes[self.itr]
            self.itr += 1
            
            map = key - 23 - 12 - 1
            while(map >= len(self.virtualPianoScale)):
                map -= 12
            while(map < 0):
                map += 12
            
            
            if(velocity == 0):
                #Spec defines velocity == 0 as an alternate notation for key release
                self.log(self.deltaTime/self.division,"~"+self.virtualPianoScale[map])
                self.notes.append([(self.deltaTime/self.division),"~"+self.virtualPianoScale[map]])
            else:
                #Real keypress
                self.log(self.deltaTime/self.division,self.virtualPianoScale[map])
                self.notes.append([(self.deltaTime/self.division),self.virtualPianoScale[map]])
                self.key_press_count += 1
                
        elif(type >> 4 == 0x8):
            #Key release
            key = self.bytes[self.itr]
            self.itr += 1
            velocity = self.bytes[self.itr]
            self.itr += 1
            
            map = key - 23 - 12 - 1
            while(map >= len(self.virtualPianoScale)):
                map -= 12
            while(map < 0):
                map += 12
            
            self.log(self.deltaTime/self.division,"~"+self.virtualPianoScale[map])
            self.notes.append([(self.deltaTime/self.division),"~"+self.virtualPianoScale[map]])
                
        elif(not type >> 4 in [0x8,0x9,0xA,0xB,0xD,0xE]):
            self.log("VoiceEvent",hex(type),hex(self.bytes[self.itr]),"DT",deltaT)
            self.itr +=1
        else:
            self.log("VoiceEvent",hex(type),hex(self.bytes[self.itr]),hex(self.bytes[self.itr+1]),"DT",deltaT)
            self.itr+=2
    
    def readEvents(self):
        while(self.itr+1 < len(self.bytes)):
            #Reset counters to 0
            for i in range(len(self.startCounter)):
                self.startCounter[i] = 0
                
            #Get to next event / MThd / MTrk
            while(self.itr+1 < len(self.bytes) and not self.checkStartSequence()):
                for i in range(len(self.startSequence)):
                    if(self.bytes[self.itr] == self.startSequence[i][self.startCounter[i]]):
                        self.startCounter[i] += 1
                    else:
                        self.startCounter[i] = 0
                        
                if(self.itr+1 < len(self.bytes)):
                    self.itr += 1
                        
                if(self.startCounter[0] == 4):
                    self.readMThd()
                elif(self.startCounter[1] == 4):
                    self.readMTrk()
    
    def log(self,*arg):
        if self.verbose or self.debug:
            for s in range(len(arg)):
                try:
                    print(str(arg[s]),end=" ")
                    self.midiRecord_list.append(str(arg[s]) + " ")
                except:
                    print("[?]",end=" ")
                    self.midiRecord_list.append("[?] ")
            print()
            if self.debug: input()
            self.midiRecord_list.append("\n")
        else:
            for s in range(len(arg)):
                try:
                    self.midiRecord_list.append(str(arg[s]) + " ")
                except:
                    self.midiRecord_list.append("[?] ")
            self.midiRecord_list.append("\n")
    
    def getInt(self,i):
        k = 0
        for n in self.bytes[self.itr:self.itr+i]:
            k = (k << 8) + n
        self.itr += i
        return k
        
    def round(i):
        up = int(i+1)
        down = int(i-1)
        if(up - i < i - down):
            return up
        else:
            return down
            
    def clean_notes(self):
        self.notes = sorted(self.notes, key=lambda x: float(x[0]))
        
        if(self.verbose):
            for x in self.notes:
                print(x)
        
        #Combine seperate lines with equal timings
        i = 0
        while(i < len(self.notes)-1):
            a_time,b_time = self.notes[i][0],self.notes[i+1][0]
            if (a_time == b_time):
                a_notes,b_notes = self.notes[i][1],self.notes[i+1][1]
                if "tempo" not in a_notes and "tempo" not in b_notes and "~" not in a_notes and "~" not in b_notes:
                    self.notes[i][1] += self.notes[i+1][1]
                    self.notes.pop(i+1)
                else:
                    i += 1
            else:
                i += 1

        #Remove duplicate notes on same line
        for q in range(len(self.notes)):
            letterDict = {}
            newline = []
            if not "tempo" in self.notes[q][1] and "~" not in self.notes[q][1]:
                for i in range(len(self.notes[q][1])):
                    if(not(self.notes[q][1][i] in letterDict)):
                        newline.append(self.notes[q][1][i])
                        letterDict[self.notes[q][1][i]] = True
                self.notes[q][1] = "".join(newline)
        return
        
    def save_song(self,song_file):
        print("Saving notes to",song_file)
        with open(song_file,"w") as f:
            f.write("playback_speed=1.0\n")
            for l in self.notes:
                f.write(str(l[0]) + " " + str(l[1]) + "\n")
        return
        
    def save_sheet(self,sheet_file):
        print("Saving sheets to",sheet_file)
        offset = self.notes[0][0]
        noteCount = 0
        with open(sheet_file,"w") as f:
            for timing,notes in self.notes:
                if not "tempo" in notes and "~" not in notes:
                    if(len(notes) > 1):
                        note = "["+notes+"]"
                    else:
                        note = notes
                    noteCount += 1
                    f.write("%7s " % note)
                    if(noteCount % 8 == 0):
                        f.write("\n")
        return
        
    def save_record(self,record_file):
        print("Saving processing log to",record_file)
        with open(record_file,"w") as f:
            for s in self.midiRecord_list:
                f.write(s)
        return
        
def get_file_choice():
    fileList = os.listdir()
    midList = []
    for f in fileList:
        if(".mid" in f or ".mid" in f.lower()):
            midList.append(f)
    print("\nType the number of a midi file press enter:\n")
    for i in range(len(midList)):
        print(i+1,":",midList[i])

    choice = int(input(">"))
    print()
    choice_index = int(choice)
    return midList[choice_index-1]
    
def main():
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        midi_file = sys.argv[1]
        if not os.path.exists(midi_file):
            print(f"Error: file not found '{midi_file}'")
            return 1
            
        if(not (".mid" in midi_file or ".mid" in midi_file.lower())):
            print(f"'{midi_file}' has an inccorect file extension")
            print("make sure this file ends in '.mid'")
            return 1
    else:
        midi_file = get_file_choice()
    
    try:
        midi = MidiFile(midi_file)
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error has occured during processing::\n\n")
        raise e
        return 1
    
    song_file = "song.txt"
    sheet_file = "sheetConversion.txt"
    
    midi.save_song(song_file)
    midi.save_sheet(sheet_file)
    print("\nSuccess, playSong is ready to run")
    input("\n\nPress any key to exit...")
    return 0
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

1.Modify the `readVoiceEvent` method to automatically simulate F1, F2, and F3 key presses based on the note ranges and updating the `virtualPianoScale`

2.Modify the `readMidiMetaEvent` method to handle tempo changes and update the current note range

my expectation is that when the midi is run it will press a new keypress (using 3 notes like this) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNuFwFADylw).

Comment: try to produce a minimal reproducible example that has the minimum of whats needed to express your problem. sending this much code at us saying find whats wrong / fix it is unlikely to yield a helpful response.